# \hfill and \hspace do not work

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

All,

I want to put three figures together in one line, spanning two columns. I used `\hfill` and `\hspace{}` in order to make the three figures fully span the horizontal width of the paper. However, after so many times I tried, I just cannot make it. There is always some space on the right, and `\hfill` or `\hspace{}` will not help to occupy the space. Below is a MWE.

Please use this link to download the figures http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=3521927653&uk=3776487005. (Click the button below in the opened page to download, the page is in Chinese.)

[image]

```
%\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\documentclass[9.5pt,conference,compsocconf,letterpaper]{IEEEtran} %ICDCS
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}

\begin{document}

%\title{xxx}
%
%\maketitle


\begin{figure*}[htp]
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}%
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{merging_and_balancing_multi_thread.eps}%
      \caption{\small Multi-thread monitoring speed with both merging and balancing optimizations.}%
      \label{fig:merging_and_balancing_multi_thread}%
  \end{minipage}\hspace{0.2cm}
  \begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}%
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{Monitoring_result_and_ground_truth.eps}%
      \caption{\small Popularity monitored by the fixed window and sliding window designs,
                compared with the popularity ground truth.}%
      \label{fig:Monitoring_result_and_ground_truth}%
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}%
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=1.05\textwidth]{Deviation_distribution.eps}%
      \caption{\small The deviation distribution.}%
      \label{fig:Deviation_distribution}%
  \end{minipage}
  \vspace{-0.6cm}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The images are not cropped and have white margins. For example, `Deviation_distribution.eps` has the bounding box:

```postscript
%%BoundingBox:    44   238   549   604
```

The real bounding box can be calculated via ghostscript:

```bash
$ gs -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE Deviation_distribution.eps
```

The result is:

```postscript
%%BoundingBox: 49 246 493 585
%%HiResBoundingBox: 49.936780 246.815992 492.839985 584.243982
```

The white margins are:

- left: 49bp - 44bp = 5bp
- bottom: 246bp - 238bp = 8bp
- right: 549bp - 493bp = 56bp
- top: 604bp - 585bp = 19bp

The `.eps` files can be fixed by replacing the `%%BoundingBox` with the result of ghostscript's `bbox` device. Or the program [`epstool --copy --bbox`](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/epstool.htm) can be used.

In case of PDF files, the images can be cropped with [`pdfcrop`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop).

With cropped images, you can then clean up the code (e.g. something like `1.1\textwidth` will usually cause overfull `\hbox` warnings).

Comment: Thank you so much for so detailed answer! I am unfamiliar with the `ghostscript` or `epstool`. Usually I use the `ps to eps` option of `GSview` to crop the white margins. But this time, I opened the eps file with an editor and changed `%%PageBoundingBox: 44   238   549   604` to `%%PageBoundingBox: 49 246 494 585`. Then I got the margin croped. PS: in your answer, the 3rd line seems should to be  `%%PageBoundingBox: 49 246 494 585`.

Comment: @Bloodmoon: `%%HiResBoundingBox` is correct. For example, this is used by option `hiresbb` of `\includegraphics` of package `graphicx`. (`hiresbb` comes from "high resolution bounding box"). `%%PageBoundingBox` makes sense for normal PostScript files that can have several pages. EPS files are limited to one page only.

Comment: I mean the 3rd line of your post, it's `%%BoundingBox:    44   238   549   604`. I opened the eps file and found that `%%BoundingBox` has the following values `49 246 494 585`, rather than `44   238   549   604`. (Compare the `3rd` and `7th` lines in your post.)

Comment: @Bloodmoon: The first values `44 238 549 604` comes from the unmodified `Deviation_distribution.eps` that I got from the Chinese web page. The values `49 246 493 585` are the values reported from ghostscript's `bbox` device.